# Magento 2 shopping cart and checkout: show discounts tax included

Tags: magento2, tax, magento2.2.6, discount, taxes

In my checkout and shopping cart discounts are appearing tax excluded. I would like to show it tax included

I'm searching where is defined the displayed value to place something like `amount * 1.21`, in order to show to the visitors this amount tax included (+21%)

By the way, In my Tax configuration, I have selected "Apply Discount On Prices, excluding tax" and it should remain like it is.

¡Thank you!